# Pointers in C, theoretical aspect

Tags: c

I have programming exam soon, and I still can't understand some things, could you guys help me?

Basically, we got:

```
char *nap[]= {"Reklamacja","Perspektywa","Reinkarnacja","Hermengilda","Audytorium","Mineralogia","Frustracja"}
```

Those are bunch of words in Polish language, but they doesn't matter at all.
So moving on, we have:

```
Size of char type on this PC : 1
Size of long type on this PC : 4
Address of beginning nap array (char type): 0x22ff20

Address of R letter in word "Reklamacja": 0x47575d,
Address of P letter in word "Perspektywa": 0x475768,
Address of R letter in word "Reinkarnacja": 0x475774,
Address of H letter in word "Hermengilda": 0x475781,
Address of A letter in word "Audytorium": 0x47578e,
Address of M letter in word "Mineralogia": 0x475799,
Address of F letter in word "Frustracja": 0x4757a5
```

The question is: what is the effect of the following line of code?

```
printf("%#lx", nap+5);
```

The correct answer is: `0x22ff34`

Why is it like so and not like `0x22ff20 + 5` which is `0x22ff25`?

Comment: Actually that has undefined behavior as far as the language standard is concerned. `"%#lx"` requires an argument of type `unsigned long`; the actual argument is a pointer. The correct way to print a pointer value is `printf("%p", (void*)(nap+5));`. The question makes some assumptions about how pointers are represented and how `printf` works. Those assumptions may be valid on your system, but they're not guaranteed.

Comment: (size_t)nap + 5 * sizeof (char*)

Comment: `char *nap[]` declare an array of char pointers, so `0x22ff34 = 0x22ff20 + 5 * sizeof(char *)` (in this case 4 bytes * 5)

Comment: @Alex: You're right. I deleted the comment.

Comment: Actually `sizeof(char *)` – the calculation is done with the array element's size, which is `char *`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is the same for *any* *typed* pointer value in C, and uses a language feature called *pointer arithmetic*.

1. What is the byte-width of the element type, including padding if a struct or union type?
2. Multiply by the index N  you're using
3. Add to the base address of the array.

The result should be the address of the N'th element in the sequence. Note you cannot portably do this with `void*`, and any cast you perform on the pointer *prior* to performing the operation will affect the outcome.

In your case, the element type of your array is `char *`. Assuming `sizeof(char*) == 4` on your platform then

1. **4 bytes**
2. 4 * 5 = **20 bytes (0x14)**
3. 0x22ff20 + 0x14 = **0x22ff34**

Remember, an array expresses as pointer-to-type with a value of the array base-address when used in the above calculation. It may seem trivial, but that is routinely the part of this that is missed.

Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

Your `nap` variable is declared as a pointer to an array of strings. So when you are using `nap+5` you are really moving the pointer 5 elements down the array (which will point to `Mineralogia`). In order to retrieve the result that you were expecting, you will have to cast the pointer so it will point to the first string, then add 5 to it to move the pointer 5 characters down. Here is a test application that I wrote up to demonstrate this (my code usually explains better than I can verbally lol):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char* nap[] = {"Reklamacja","Perspektywa","Reinkarnacja","Hermengilda","Audytorium","Mineralogia","Frustracja"};

    //Returns the beginning address of nap
    printf("%#lx\r\n", nap);

    //Returns the sixth string in nap (aka nap[5] since arrays are 0-based index)
    //and the address
    printf("%s %#lx\r\n", *(nap+5), nap+5);

    //Returns the first string in the array (aka nap[0]) and the address
    printf("%s %#lx\r\n", *nap, *nap);

    //Returns the 1st string in the array starting at the 6th letter and the address
    printf("%s %#lx\r\n", *nap+5, *nap+5);

    return 0;
}
```

Also remember that a `char` is 4 bytes so the last `printf` statement moved the pointer 20 bytes down the string.

Answer (score 1):

`nap` is a pointer to the first item of the array: `nap == &(nap[0])`.

`nap+5` is a pointer to the sixth item of the array: `nap+5 == &(nap[5])`.

Each item of your array is 4 bytes long (test for `sizeof(char *)`), so the numerical value of `nap+5` is a numerical value of `nap` plus 5 times 4:

```
0x22ff20 + 4*5 = 0x22ff20 + 0x14 = 0x22ff34
```

Comment: `nap` is not a pointer, it is an array.  `nap+0` is a pointer, and `nap` decays as a pointer in the the first expression.